# Javascript/Python - Trouble Clicking Button

Tags: javascript, python, forms, button

I'm using Python's module Spynner for creating a Social Network application, one of the features is being able to create a Tumblr account directly in the application without loading a web browser. Using the ability to run javascript code in the browser, I'm attempting to click a dynamic button, except any idea I use doesn't seem to click it at all. The button's code looks like this, nice and simple.

```
<button id="signup_forms_submit">
        <span class="account_btn">Démarrer</span>
        <span class="birthday_btn">Suivant</span>
        <span class="captcha_btn"><span>Terminé !</span></span>
        <span class="login_btn">Connexion</span>
</button>
```

I've tried the following with no results, the button just won't click.

```
browser.runjs("""$(document.elementFromPoint(393, 373)).click();  """)
browser.runjs("""$('.account_btn').click();""")
browser.click("input[id=signup_forms_submit]", wait_load=True,  timeout=30)
```

I'm honestly stuck. Any help is apprecieated.

Comment: Where did you get those coordinates `(393, 373)` from? What is `browser`? We need more context.

Comment: Browser is "Spynner", from the description. The coords I got from using Spynner to take a screenshot from within the browser. After I opened photoshop to get the x,y. I've used this method in the past before and it's worked flawlessly, except right now.

Comment: Try reading the page source and/or javascript and see if you can figure out what action is taken on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Set confirm callback before clicking an element:

https://pythonhosted.org/spynner/spynner.browser.Browser-class.html#set_javascript_confirm_callback